# Difference between Spring application run-one-time techniques?

Tags: java, spring, startup

As with most frameworks Spring offers more than one way to do something. I am considering the goal of how to run a Java method one time only at application startup. I have found at least 2 ways to do this with Spring.

One way is to make a Java class into a Spring bean. Add something like the following to a config XML file:

```
<bean name="com.mycomp.service.EngineImpl"
        class="com.mycomp.service.EngineImpl" />

    <bean name="/Engine" autowire="byName"
        class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
        <property name="service"
            ref="com.mycomp.service.EngineImpl" />
        <property name="serviceInterface"
            value="com.mycomp.client.Engine" />
</bean>
```

Then in the EngineImpl class put an annotation on the method I want to run at startup:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
}
```

Another way is to add this to the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    com.mycomp.engine.config.MyConfigClass
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then in class MyConfigClass add
    @Configuration

above the class declaration, then put the code I want to run into the constructor of the class.

What are the pros and cons of each? Is one way better?

Answer (score 0):

both does the job, point here is to find the place which is better for the type of initialization you are attempting to do and also if you really want the bean or just creating for initialization purpose